# Android - how to keep UI elements static between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a navigation bar with buttons which I would like to share between multiple activities:

[image]

Currently, when I start the same activity (for example, click on LOST.DIR) the whole screen changes, including the navigation bar (new list of folders appears).

I would like to keep the navigation bar static (to persist between same activity types and not to change or re appear after starting a new activity).

Is this possible?

Comment: hey did I answer your question? If so can you accept the answer for completeness. Share that SO love!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use one activity and [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

But, if you really must use multiple activities. Another approach would be to use an actionbar, ([actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is great for this) and have the menu switch between your different activities. The menu drop down can either be a list of icons on the action bar or a drop down spinner located in the top right of the actionbar. This actionbar will be static throughout your activities and consist of the same list of categories (i.e. the ones of your navigation bar).

Answer (score 1):

Not straight away. Activities are exactly the opposite of what you want: they are independent pieces of interface.

You can use `Fragments`, or embed your activities in a master activity. `TabHost` does this, for example.

Comment: Don't use TabHost. TabHosts are really ugly, unmanageable (especially with separate Activities), and generally advised against.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for total control is to write your own custom class which takes a LinearLayout as a constructor argument and handles the visibility, click dispatching (via delegates), images etc of each button.

Add methods to do all of the above and whatever other functionality you need.

Create a layout.xml and  it in each of your Activity layouts.

Instantiate your button bar class in each Activity and pass it the reference to it's layout that you get with findViewById on your content view.

As others have said, there are existing solutions and you might ask "why invent a new wheel".  I have just such a class I use in many of my projects and it was a lot of work to do version one but now I have a class which I can totally control, add to, fix and customise with ease.

Something like this:

```
bar.setButtonClickHandler(Button.Favourites, favouritesButtonClickHandler);
bar.setButtonVisibility(Button.Edit, View.INVISIBLE);
```

etc

I've used a LinearLayout but if I have have the need to use something else, it's a simple matter to overload the constructors to accept, for example, a RelativeLayout argument.